# Kendo Scheduler not refreshing when dynamically resized

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Our app is setup with your basic header, footer, left nav, and content pane.  We also have a dynamic right pane which we call "Quick View".  If you click a link that targets Quick View, the right pane will slide out from the right.  This causes the content pane to shrink horizontally so the right, Quick View pane displays.

When we have the Kendo Scheduler displayed in the content area and click a link that causes the Quick View pane to slide into view from right, the Scheduler does resize with the content area, but the events are not refreshed.  Example would be if in week view initial display is fine.  Slide in the Quick View causeing Scheduler to shrink in width.  Day columns shrink as expected but none of the events change at all.  This makes what was scheduled on Thursday to now appear to be scheduled on Saturday.

If I manually resize the browser at all, it triggers the refresh and all is well.  Problem with that is 2 fold:
1.  I don't want to require my users to resize the browser, of course.
2.  Then closing the Quick View has the right pane slide back out the right cause the Scheduler to grow in size and again, the events do not move making them appear to be on different days.

I guess I could put in a hack to programmatically refresh Scheduler after my Quick View slides in or out, but that is a hack.

Suggestions please.